# Looking for a Selenium Python with Behave BDD automation expert

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am looking for a Selenium Python with Behave BDD automation expert who can guide me in my real automation project. I have done Udemy courses, and have also watched the videos on youtube. These videos use some very basic examples that do not cover the real world scenarios, for example, if I want to test the following scenario:

1. Establish the geo-location
2. Visit the website on a particular browser (based on what is returned by my script i.e., chrome, firefox, or edge. I am using a browser list and a for loop to get the browser and install the driver accordingly).
3. Establish if the user is anon (which the user would be).
4. Visit the test URLs.
5. perform actions.

I have done all the above individually and it kind of works. This is just one example. Have many more.

BUT I AM STRUGGLING WITH THE FOLLOWING:

1. where to store the drivers or shall I do the installation during the runtime - what is the best practice
2. do I store all the identifiers in a separate file in utilities or just identify the objects in the code snippet that runs at the time.
3. What is the framework I should use - I am sure there are many out there.
4. Where in my framework shall I add the Behave feature files, scenarios, Steps etc.

Basically being my very first project I need a professional guidance and I am ready to pay for the guidance. Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework has a complete behave/BDD integration.

Behave examples with SeleniumBase: [SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd)

```bash
> cd examples/behave_bdd/
> behave features/realworld.feature -T -D dashboard -k

Dashboard: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
********************************************************************************
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the RealWorld App # features/realworld.feature:1

  Scenario: Verify RealWorld App (log in / sign out)  # features/realworld.feature:3
    Given Open "seleniumbase.io/realworld/login"      # ../../sbase/steps.py:10
    And Clear Session Storage                         # ../../sbase/steps.py:391
    When Type "demo_user" into "#username"            # ../../sbase/steps.py:28
    And Type "secret_pass" into "#password"           # ../../sbase/steps.py:28
    And Do MFA "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG" into "#totpcode"    # ../../sbase/steps.py:194
    Then Assert exact text "Welcome!" in "h1"         # ../../sbase/steps.py:85
    And Highlight "img#image1"                        # ../../sbase/steps.py:95
    And Click 'a:contains("This Page")'               # ../../sbase/steps.py:19
    And Save screenshot to logs                       # ../../sbase/steps.py:120
    When Click link "Sign out"                        # ../../sbase/steps.py:104
    Then Assert element 'a:contains("Sign in")'       # ../../sbase/steps.py:60
    And Assert text "You have been signed out!"       # ../../sbase/steps.py:77
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

- Dashboard: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
--- LogPath: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/latest_logs/
==================================================================================
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
12 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m4.682s
```

Another example, which uses higher-level Behave steps to simplify the `.feature` file:

```bash
> cd examples/behave_bdd/
> behave features/calculator.feature:61 -T -D dashboard -k

Dashboard: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
********************************************************************************
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Calculator App # features/calculator.feature:1

  Background:   # features/calculator.feature:3

  Scenario: 7.0 × (3 + 3) = 42        # features/calculator.feature:49
    Given Open the Calculator App     # features/steps/calculator.py:4
    When Press C                      # features/steps/calculator.py:9
    And Press 7                       # features/steps/calculator.py:79
    And Press .                       # features/steps/calculator.py:104
    And Press 0                       # features/steps/calculator.py:94
    And Press ×                       # features/steps/calculator.py:29
    And Press (                       # features/steps/calculator.py:14
    And Press 3                       # features/steps/calculator.py:59
    And Press +                       # features/steps/calculator.py:39
    And Press 3                       # features/steps/calculator.py:59
    And Press )                       # features/steps/calculator.py:19
    Then Verify output is "7.0×(3+3)" # features/steps/calculator.py:135
    When Press =                      # features/steps/calculator.py:44
    Then Verify output is "42"        # features/steps/calculator.py:135
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

- Dashboard: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
--- LogPath: /Users/michael/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/latest_logs/
==================================================================================
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 8 skipped
14 steps passed, 0 failed, 60 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m1.672s
```

⚪ With the Dashboard enabled, you'll get one of these:

[image]

#### Behave-Gherkin files:

The `*.feature` files can use any step seen from:

```bash
behave --steps-catalog
```

SeleniumBase includes several pre-made Behave steps, which you can use by creating a Python file with the following line in your `features/steps/` directory:

```py
from seleniumbase.behave import steps  # noqa
```

Inside your `features/environment.py` file, you should have the following:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from seleniumbase.behave import behave_sb
behave_sb.set_base_class(BaseCase)  # Accepts a BaseCase subclass
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import before_all  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import before_feature  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import before_scenario  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import before_step  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import after_step  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import after_scenario  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import after_feature  # noqa
from seleniumbase.behave.behave_sb import after_all  # noqa
```

If you've already created a subclass of `BaseCase` with custom methods, you can swap `BaseCase` in with your own subclass, which will allow you to easily use your own custom methods in your Behave step definitions.

Here's an example Python file in the `features/steps/` folder:

```py
from behave import step


@step("Open the Swag Labs Login Page")
def go_to_swag_labs(context):
    sb = context.sb
    sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
    sb.clear_local_storage()


@step("Login to Swag Labs with {user}")
def login_to_swag_labs(context, user):
    sb = context.sb
    sb.type("#user-name", user)
    sb.type("#password", "secret_sauce\n")


@step("Verify that the current user is logged in")
def verify_logged_in(context):
    sb = context.sb
    sb.assert_element("#header_container")
    sb.assert_element("#react-burger-menu-btn")
    sb.assert_element("#shopping_cart_container")


@step('Add "{item}" to cart')
def add_item_to_cart(context, item):
    sb = context.sb
    sb.click('div.inventory_item:contains("%s") button[name*="add"]' % item)
```

A `*.feature` file could look like this:

```
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Swag Labs App

  Background:
    Given Open the Swag Labs Login Page

  Scenario: User can order a backpack from the store
    When Login to Swag Labs with standard_user
    Then Verify that the current user is logged in
    And Save price of "Backpack" to <item_price>
    When Add "Backpack" to Cart
    Then Verify shopping cart badge shows 1 item(s)
    When Click on shopping cart icon
    And Click Checkout
    And Enter checkout info: First, Last, 12345
    And Click Continue
    Then Verify 1 "Backpack"(s) in cart
    And Verify cost of "Backpack" is <item_price>
    And Verify item total is $29.99
    And Verify tax amount is $2.40
    And Verify total cost is $32.39
    When Click Finish
    Then Verify order complete
    When Logout from Swag Labs
    Then Verify on Login page
```

Here's another example of a `*.feature` file:

```
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the RealWorld App

  Scenario: Verify RealWorld App (log in / sign out)
    Given Open "seleniumbase.io/realworld/login"
    And Clear Session Storage
    When Type "demo_user" into "#username"
    And Type "secret_pass" into "#password"
    And Do MFA "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG" into "#totpcode"
    Then Assert text "Welcome!" in "h1"
    And Highlight element "img#image1"
    And Click 'a:contains("This Page")'
    And Save screenshot to logs
    When Click link "Sign out"
    Then Assert element 'a:contains("Sign in")'
    And Assert text "You have been signed out!"
```

If there's a test failure, that's easy to spot:

```bash
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Fail Page # features/fail_page.feature:1

  Scenario: Fail test on purpose to see what happens  # features/fail_page.feature:3
    When Open the Fail Page                           # features/steps/fail_page.py:4
    Then Fail test on purpose                         # features/steps/fail_page.py:9
      Assertion Failed: This test fails on purpose!
      Captured stdout:
      >>> STEP FAILED:  (#2) Fail test on purpose
      Class / Feature:  SeleniumBase scenarios for the Fail Page
      Test / Scenario:  Fail test on purpose to see what happens

   ❌ Scenario Failed!
```

️ For convenience, the [SeleniumBase Behave GUI](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/behave_gui.md) lets you run `behave` scripts from a Desktop app.

️ To launch it, call `sbase behave-gui` or `sbase gui-behave`:

```bash
sbase behave-gui
* Starting the SeleniumBase Behave Commander GUI App...
```

[image]

️ You can customize the tests that show up there:

```bash
sbase behave-gui  # all tests
sbase behave-gui -i=calculator  # tests with "calculator" in the name
sbase behave-gui features/  # tests located in the "features/" folder
sbase behave-gui features/calculator.feature  # tests in that feature
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Mintz for such a comprehensive answer. It will take me a while to go through it but I really appreciate you help.